# how do i get map hilight to work

Tags: jquery, imagemap

I can't figure out how to get the jQuery plugin 'maphilight' to work. Remember that I don't know much about web design in general so it may be some stupid problem that I can't find because of my inexperience.

My jQuery reference is fine and I referenced maphilight like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
```

My img does have a usemap reference to the map and it works fine so that's not it. This is a shortened version of how my map tag looks like:

```
<map name="downmap" class="floorMap">
    <area title="title" onclick="loadRoom('room name');" coords="98,425,98,446,146,446,146,540,216,540,216,425" />
</map>
```

And in my javascript file, I have this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.floorMap').maphilight({ stroke: false, fillColor: '009DDF', fillOpacity: 1 });
});
```

Based on everything I researched, I thought this would work, but it doesn't. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Your importing jquery-min.js right?

Comment: Yes, there's an error that says object has no method 'maphilight', and yes, I'm importing jQuery like this: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

Read this documentation and use script given in example
http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

Comment: I've looked at that page many times, but I just noticed the "Tested On:" section and it seems that it hasn't been tested for any of the latest versions of the browsers. Is the difference between versions significant enough for it to make sense that it's not working?

Comment: I keep trying all of the examples but they don't work. It's not my image map because I know it works without the plugin.